# Angular 5: How do you hide/show one item at a time in the same function?

Tags: angular, angular5

So far I have this in HTML file:

```html
<button (click)="showStuff()">Show Example</button>
<div [hidden]="isHidden">Example 1: I like puppies.</div>

<button (click)="Show example2">Show Example</button>
<div [hidden]="isHidden">Example2: I like horses.</div>
```

---

And this in TypeScript file:

```js
isHidden = true;

showStuff() {
  this.isHidden = !this.isHidden;
}
```

It triggers both divs at the same time. How can I trigger the one I click on only using Angular 2 or 5?

Comment: `<button (click)="Show example2">Show Example</button>?` Where is the function call?

Answer (score 0):

If it requires you to have a single function only then you can create an array of booleans to keep track of hidden state.

**Template**

```
<button (click)="showStuff(0)">Show Example</button>
<div [hidden]="isHidden[0]">Example 1: I like puppies.</div>

<button (click)="showStuff(1)">Show Example</button>
<div [hidden]="isHidden[1]">Example2: I like horses.</div>
```

**Component**

```
isHidden: boolean[] = [true, true];

showStuff(index: number) {
  this.isHidden[index] = !this.isHidden[index];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

No need to write any TypeScript code. Just use below code

```js
<button (click)="isHidden1 = !isHidden1">Show Example</button>
<div [hidden]="isHidden1">Example 1: I like puppies.</div>

<button (click)="isHidden2 = !isHidden2">Show Example</button>
<div [hidden]="isHidden2">Example2: I like horses.</div>
```

Comment: This will not work in prod mode. As in prod, compiler searches the variables in ts file.

Comment: @Paresh it's working fine on my side even in production mode also

Comment: Strange. I got errors that the `variable` not found in the component. So I had to add them to the component also.

Answer (score 0):

```
In the above code snippet shared, both the <div> tags 'hidden' attribute is tied up with "isHidden" property declared in the typescript file using property binding. 

so on button click the value of isHidden is tied up with both the <div> using property binding, the updated value gets applied to both the div's

Solution: 

 - Either define two different properties for each div.
or can manipulate isHidden accordingly as show above.
```